# uft not capturing installshield or msi screens

Tags: installshield, hp-uft

We are trying to automate the installation testing using UFT.
But, UFT is not capturing the installshield screens when we click on record.
Any suggestions?

It is just showing empty test case when we click on record.

Even manual creation of scripts also not showing.

Installshield setup.exe uses internally msiexec.exe.
Does it effect anything as the background process name is changing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected **Record and run test on any open Windows-based application** in the `Record` -> `Record and Run Settings`?

If you have and it still doesn't work, it may be that the installation is running in a higher security level than UFT.

You could try using UFT's [Insight](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2019/04/03/image-based-testing-with-insight/) option in order to work around this.

Comment: yes, I selected that option. But still getting this

Comment: Insight is image based right, which is not a feasible one as we need to change scripts everytime marketing team change banners.